# Getting error when instantiating RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I am trying to launch chrome browser using RemoteWebDriver with the following code.

```
File file = new File("E:\\S\\chromedriver.exe"); //path to the chromedriver.exe so downloaded
//System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
//capability.setVersion("38.0.2125.122 m");
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9898/"),capability);
```

I got the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure.

I've checked that the port 9898 is open. I've added localhost in hosts in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Update:
I can see two more exceptions.

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:9515 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused.

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
```

Comment: Which version of chrome and chrome driver are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: And which chrome driver?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the chromedriver version. The file says chromedriver.exe.

Comment: no version number I can find.

Comment: I've updated my chromedriver and chrome. The chrome browser version is 72.0.3626.121. The chrome driver version is 2.46. The error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your chrome version fits to your chromedriver. 
I am not quiet sure which port should/can be used but you could try following options:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9898"), capability);
```

or

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9515"), capability);
```

**Running tests local**

You can use `new ChromeDriver(capabilities);`

**Running tests remote**

You need the selenium server to be installed. Can be installed on your local machine too. You can find it here: https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
When installed and running you can connect to it using the RemoteWebDriver.

You can get more information in the selenium docs https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#running-standalone-selenium-server-for-use-with-remotedrivers

Comment: I can see two more exceptions. I've mentioned them in the update section of the question.

Comment: I've used both your suggestions, but no luck.

Comment: What if you use `new ChromeDriver(capability));`? Should be no problem as long as you need it just localy.

Comment: Yeah, for now. But I want to learn the usage of RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: Thanks for the info.